# Vue.js: Passing anonymous functions in props object

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm trying to extend the select2 example to be more practically useful. So far I've added multiselect functionality, and trying to allow custom select2 configuration.

https://jsfiddle.net/5ytm3LL6/

It appears that function properties of props objects are being stripped when handed to component.

**What is a solution for a parent to give widget component configuration with js functions?**

I'm somewhat confused, because the embedded version actually shows params being transferred properly in the built-in console output, while jsfiddle browser console output does not. **However, both versions do not pass the functions to select2 widget.**

```js
Vue.component('select2', {
  props: ['options', 'value', 'params'],
  template: '<select><slot></slot></select>',
  mounted: function () {
    var vm = this, params = $.extend({}, this.params || {});
    console.log(this.params, params);
    params.data = this.options;
    $(this.$el).val(this.value).select2(params).on('change', function () {
      vm.$emit('input', $(vm.$el).val());
    });
  },
  watch: {
    value: function (value) {
      var $el = $(this.$el);
      if (!_.isEqual($el.val(), value)) {
        $el.select2('val', value);
      }
    },
    options: function (options) {
      $(this.$el).select2({ data: options });
    }
  },
  destroyed: function () { $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy'); }
});

new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      value: 'a',
      options: [{id:'a', label:'A'}, {id:'b', label:'B'}],
      params: {
        test: 'TEST',
        formatSelection: function (item) {return item.label;},
        formatResult: function (item) {return item.label;}
      }
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/select2/dist/css/select2.css"></style>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/select2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select2 v-model="value" :options="options" :params="params"></select2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see js functions you have passed being printed in console log. I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ytm3LL6/1/) and put following logs in `select2` compoent:

```
console.log(params.formatResult);
console.log(params.formatSelection);
```

Which prints following:

```
function (item) {return item.label;}
function (item) {return item.label;}
```